# Migrating document libraries from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010

Tags: migration, content-database

I need help in my migration process.  First I have a test environment which is configured for SharePoint 2010 and I need to migrate a web application from SharePoint Server 2007 to SharePoint 2010 using database attach.

I requested the database team to make me a backup and restore and they made it successfully. I have crated a new web application with no site collection depending on attaching the database but when I attached it the number of site collection appears is 0 and the site wont open for me.

Did I miss something ?

Do I need to create the site collection first before I attach the database?
Please help, I have been into this issue for a whole week with no successful results. I just made this whole process to migrate document libraries from sharepoint 2007 to 2010.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create the site collection, but you do need to ensure that the database you are attaching contains the root collection from the old web app. Your WebApp should be created with the same URL, AAM, and managed paths as well.

How are you adding your database to SharePoint?  If you are using CA, than that could be your problem because I don't believe that will kick off the upgrade.  You need to use Powershell CMDLET `Mount-SPContentDatabase` or the STSADM command `stsadm -o addcontentdb`

Once the database is attached to the new SQL instance you can run

```
Test-SPContentDatabase -Name <DatabaseName> -WebApplication <URL>
```

This will give you a report on some of the issues you will encounter with the Contents of the DB.  You can run this before adding it to your WebApp (and should, as adding it to the WebApp will trigger an upgrade). You can run this after an upgrade to see if there are any lingering issues as well.

Microsoft has some very good videos on the upgrade process:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff420396

as well as the Technet article:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263299.aspx#VerifyCustom

Comment: thank you jesus for your help , i will list what i have done : the database have just been backup and restoredto SQL is this fine? and it contains the root collection . and for the URL should it be the same name becouse another guy who is left now made the migration before using different URL name ? and yes i used the command addcontentdb but also it doesnt work it says complete successfully but the site doesnt open and the site collection are 0,,,, sorry for all questions but im really new to sharepoint i just worked for 5 monthes then the manager asks us for upgrading :( im reading now more

Comment: If is preferable to run test-spcontentdb prior to adding to WebApp, but you can still do it afterwards.  Yes, the URL should be the same or you wont be able to access the content without making modifications to the site collections.  You can check the upgrade status from Central Administration (under Upgrade and Migration), this will show you if SP had any issues upgrading your DB.

Comment: The url does NOT have to be the same. The webapp itself will have a zone with a url which will function as the starting address. I have done this many times. How would you move a db to a new server while the old url is still in use otherwise? (And adding a hosts file entry will only work for machines not using a proxy since most proxies will overrule the hosts file)